# Assigning a variable using a class method within the constructor of a structure

Tags: c++, hash

I have a class called `hash_t`. The class contains a struct called `node_t`, with its respective constructor.

```
    struct node_t
{   node_t *next;
    string key;
    TYPE data;


    node_t(string _key, TYPE &_data)
    {   next = nullptr;
        data = _data;
        key = _key;
    }
};
```

Using a hash_t method shown below, we take the key, pass it to mkHash and return a hashed version of the key.:

```
uint64_t mkHash(const string &strng)
{   const unsigned char *str = (const unsigned char*)(strng.c_str());
    unsigned char ch;
    uint64_t rslt = 5123;
    while ((ch=*str++) != '\0')
        rslt = rslt * 33 + ch;
    return rslt;
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do, is change the node_t class to create a hash in it's constructor, to compare hash values instead of the keys, as this should use less comparisons. My thought process was to run the `mkHash` method inside of the constructor to assign a hash to `node_t` as such:

```
struct node_t
{   node_t *next;
    string key;
    TYPE data;
    uint64_t hsh;

    node_t(string _key, TYPE &_data)
    {   next = nullptr;
        data = _data;
        key = _key;
        hsh = mkHash(key);
    }
};
```

And I'm getting this from MinGW:

```
error: cannot call member function 'uint64_t hash_t<TYPE>::mkHash(const string&) [with TYPE = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; uint64_t = long long unsigned int; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]' without object
```

How do I get the constructor of `node_t` to accept the method call for assignment? I'm not sure what's going wrong, or how to fix it, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although the issue here appears to be rather simple, in the past the seemingly simple problems turned out to be something else because the question failed to meet all requirements of a [mre], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. What you need to do is take a [tour] of stackoverflow.com, read the instructions for [ask] questions here, then come back here and [edit] your question until it meets all requirements of a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feeling incredibly silly at this one, I've worked it out. Changed the declaration of `mkHash` to be `static` and actually used the correct scope for the hash_t method:

```
struct node_t
{   node_t *next;
    string key;
    TYPE data;
    uint64_t hsh;

    node_t(string _key, TYPE &_data)
    {   next = nullptr;
        data = _data;
        key = _key;
        hsh = hash_t::mkHash(key);
    }
};
```

Thank you for the contributions